# Color based on mesh height Three.js

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, mesh

I am loading in an STL file with the STLLoader() in Three.js and am transforming it into a mesh. Now, I would like to color each cube of my mesh based on its height, as in the image attached here [screenshot-color-by-height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXPEw.png). Is this possible within Three.js and if so, what would be the best approach? The actual model is here:

https://casagroupproject.github.io/subpage1.html

Comment: You can use shaders or set colors of vertices in your model's geometry.

Comment: is it also possible to use the TextureLoader? something like `var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
                     map: loader.load('delhiTex.jpg'),
                     side: THREE.DoubleSide
                     })`

Answer (score 1):

Just a concept of how you can make it with colors of vertices:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10);
planeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
var yMin = 0;
var yMax = 2;
var colors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < planeGeom.attributes.position.count; i++) {
  let yVal = THREE.Math.randInt(yMin, yMax);
  let yNorm = (yVal - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
  planeGeom.attributes.position.setY(i, yVal);
  colors.push(yNorm, yNorm, 1);
}
planeGeom.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
planeGeom.computeVertexNormals();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
}));
scene.add(mesh)

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks -  I'll give it a try!

Comment: @emily Just out of curiousity, was it helpful?

Comment: it was useful to know in general but I ended up going with another solution!

Comment: @emily Is there any link to the solution you've used? Really interesting :)

Comment: I ended up using the built in MeshNormalMaterial() due to lack of time (https://casagroupproject.github.io/cities.html#london)